# Object is of type 'unknown' rxjs angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing with strange issue with typescript.

Vscode can inffer type of response
But when run compiler still throw error **Object is of type 'unknown' typescript**

I am facing with strange issue with typescript
Vscode can inffer type of response
[image]

Comment: make `console.log(res);` value is exist or not. may be response is not convert into specified type.

Comment: hi @ParthM.Dave
res is exist
but when compiled, the compiler throw an error Object is of type 'unknown' typescript
Any idea for this error

Comment: Ok @ben dan  try to make `res: ReferalConfig[]` type will solve your issue.